# SharedPreference in a separate class?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am attempting to create a class that will contain methods for saving and loading an ArrayList of objects into SharedPreferences. However, when I attempt to load back data I had previously saved. It is as if it has not saved. I am using Googles Gson Libraries to help.

**Instance_Read_Write.java**

```
public class Instance_Read_Write {
    public void saveData(Context context, ArrayList<Example> Examples){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("instanceKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(Examples);
        editor.putString("list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void loadData(Context context, ArrayList<Example> Examples) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("instanceKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("list", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>() {}.getType();
        Examples = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if (Examples == null) {
            Examples = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is how I am referencing them.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Instance_Read_Write instance_read_write = new Instance_Read_Write();
instance_read_write.loadData(context,Examples);
Examples.add(new Example("test"));

    ...
    ...
    ...

   instance_read_write.saveData(context,Examples);
```

Is there a way to make this work? or perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: Your `loadData` does not look correct - you pass in `Examples` but then override it with the result of `gson.fromJson` and so it is never returned.  You would need to operate on Examples such as `.add` or `.addAll`.

Comment: I am a little confused, do you mean something along the lines of .add(gson.fromJson(json, type));? Something like this throws me NullPointerExceptions as is the case with AddAll(), I believe I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have tried making these methods local in the classes I use them, they do work in there current state, minus the arguments. Could it perhaps be my arguments? Contexts is essentially "this", and my ArrayList<Example> Examples is a reference to my passed ArrayList I am looking to manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This addresses one error in your posted code namely the treatment of the `Examples` parameter in the method `loadData` method.

Since it seems your intention of the `loadData` is to always produce an ArrayList then I'd recommend returning the instance.  Alternatively, you would have to first create an empty ArrayList and pass that in and then operate on it.

So using the approach of returning the ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Example> loadData(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Example> result;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("instanceKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>() {}.getType();
    result = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (result == null) {
        result = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return result;
}

// ... and the calling code (in MainActivity) looks like:
Examples = instance_read_write.loadData(context);
```

Not to stoke up a pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference discussion - it appears you are expecting `Example` actual parameter to be updated by assigning it in the body of the method - which it will not - you can only operate on the object to affect it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/2711811.

To complete the topic, here's a solution which would continue your intention of passing in the `Examples` object:

```
// In calling method...
Examples = new ArrayList<Example>;
instance_read_write.loadData(context,Examples);



//...in class Instance_Read_Write...

public void loadData(Context context, ArrayList<Example> Examples) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("instanceKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<Example> t = gson.fromJson(json, type);
   
    if (t != null) {
        Examples.addAll(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to have solved my issue. Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Token for the Type, put

```
Examples = gson.fromJson(json, Example.class);
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: Hey thanks for your reccomendation, however nothing happens. The fromJson() requests a Type as its second argument. So when I cast Example.class, its has if nothing changed sadly.